# Fit survival-like data or inversed S-curves

Tags: r, curve-fitting, survival-analysis

I am dealing with some data producing survival-like curves where, instead of time vs survival, I have the log concentration of a substrate against bacterial optical density. The higher the concentration, the lower the OD. And lethal concentration varies with bacterial strain. I am attaching a plot to illustrate all that, where I show five bacterial strains. Each point in the graphic represents three independent replicates. I did not plot them for clarity purposes.
The questions are:
1- Can I use survival and survminer libraries, which are devoted to survival studies?
2- If not, how can I adjust such curves? An alternative would be to focus on the part of the curves where OD starts decreasing, but I do not fancy that idea that much.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.
Best,
David[image]

Comment: No. That kind of data does not fit the survival analysis paradigm. You should be looking for packages that handle phamacokinetics or chemical reaction kinetics. You should also be asking such questions elsewhere. SO is not for methods and package recommendations, nor is it for multipart questions. Please review the Help Center before asking.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I got this wrong. Best, David